# Deploy app on nodester

Tags: git, node.js, nodester

i am going crazy :(
I want to setup an app to nodester with windows7.
I followed the instructions on http://nodester.com/help

At first i set up git, installed git, genereated a ssh-key and set it up to my profile.
Everything works how it is written in the description. ssh -T git@github.com works fine aswell. I have done all these steps with git shell.

Now i want to push my app to nodester using powershell.

```
npm install nodester-cli -g - worked
nodester user setup <> <>   - worked
 nodester info verifying credentials
 nodester info user verified..
 nodester warn No key file found, encrypt is not going to be strong.
 nodester info writing user data to config
  and a file was .nodester was created in my directory

nodester user setkey        - does not work
 nodester ERROR sshkey was not found: .ssh\id_rsa.pub
 nodester not ok!
```

Maybe the reason is, that the key is in C:\Users\ME\ .ssh\id_rsa.pub ?
How can i change the path?

Now i have done the following:

```
nodester app create <>
nodester app info <>
git init                 - worked
git add .                - worked
git commit -m "init"     - worked
git remote add nodester <key from nodester app info>
 everything went fine until now
git push nodester master - does not work
 Nodester!
 Connection closed by 50.16.203.53
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 and the repository exists.
```

Can someone help me to find a solution?

Comment: The solution is very easy. I have to set the path with "nodester user setkey C:\Users\Me\.ssh\id_rsa.pub" instead of "nodester user setkey". There is just one problem left: i have always to set the user setup and the setkey when i change the directory else i can not connect to nodester. That means that i have in every folder a .nodester file but i can live with that.